# Elasticsearch search on number field

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I am new to elasticsearch. Apologies if the question sounds very basic. I am not able to get the answer directly from the documentations.

Is there a way to do a search on number field with the returned docs score ranked based on how close the number is to the input filter. 
I mean,

- if I have 10 docs in the index, let's say book objects
- and the prices   of them are 1 to 10 if I search for book price of 12$
- I want to get
  the book of 10$ at the top and 9$ next and so forth...

Is it possible with elasticsearch?

Comment: Assuming we have the 1 to 10 price and you search for 5$; what is the order that you are expecting?

Comment: 5$ at the top, 4$ or 6$ in the next two spots, 3$ and 7$ in next two, 2$ and 8$ next, 1$ and 9$ at the next two, 10$ at the bottom. Basically, sorted by the difference (absolute val of diff) between the input and the value we have.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you sorting docs on elastic response, if you have to do it in elasticsearch you can look at stript_score function: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-script-score.